# Problema para hacer consulta de cantidades entre 2 tablas sql

Tags: sql

Buen día, tengo 2 tablas; 1 de solicitud de traslado de piezas y 1 del traslado en si. Ambas tienen en comun el número de referencia base y logro enlazarlas sin problema. La problemática está cuando intento consultar las cantidades de unidades trasladadas. Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT T0.[ItemCode], T0.[Dscription], T0.[Quantity] as 'Cantidad Solicitada', T1.[Quantity] as 'Cantidad Trasladada' FROM WTR1 T0 INNER JOIN WTQ1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[TrgetEntry] WHERE T0.[ItemCode] Like 'CKD%%'
```

Y este el resultado:

```
CODIGO              DESCRIPCION                  CANT. S  CANT. T
CKD371200-WJ351-01  MANDO DERECHO HORSE        ||  1,00 ||  1,00    
CKD303000-WJ351-00  RELE DE INTERMITENTE HORSE ||  2,00 ||  1,00    
CKD371200-WJ351-01  MANDO DERECHO HORSE        ||  1,00 ||  2,00    
CKD303000-WJ351-00  RELE DE INTERMITENTE HORSE ||  2,00 ||  2,00
```

Cuando en realidad debería ser:

```
CODIGO              DESCRIPCION                  CANT. S  CANT. T
CKD371200-WJ351-01  MANDO DERECHO HORSE        ||  1,00 ||  1,00    
CKD303000-WJ351-00  RELE DE INTERMITENTE HORSE ||  2,00 ||  2,00
```

No entiendo porque me duplica y suma la cantidad de las unidades trasladadas. Agradecería toda su ayuda.

Comment: Hola Marcos, bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español. Por favor, utiliza la opción [edit] para agregar: 1.- La estructura de tus tablas 2.- Un ejemplo de los datos 3.- Tu consutla SQL 4.- El resultado esperado. Gracias!

Comment: O usas `DISTINCT` o agregas todas las claves foráneas en el inner join, en este caso creo que falta `TO.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode`

Comment: Me funciono colocando la clave foránea que me faltaba tal como lo sugeriste. Muchas gracias.

Comment: @javdromero ¿como es adivinaste que existia `T1.ItemCode`?

Comment: @Marcos Supongo que lo dedujo al ver T0.[Quantity] y T1.[Quantity], excelente trabajo.

Comment: @MarcosValera Mas bien diría, mágia! ; ) Espero que de esto veas lo importante de compartir la estructura de tus tablas y demás información.

Comment: @Marcos Por los nombres de tablas y campos, estoy casi seguro que es SAP B1. En su momento trabajé con ese ERP. Saludos!